# Rails -- working with an existing db, cannot run migrations without losing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sqlite

I am a beginner working with Rails 4.1. I am trying to integrate an existing sqlite3 db with my app in the development environment.

To try to get this to work, I've followed the steps listed at Joel Berghoff's [blog](http://blog.joelberghoff.com/2013/02/06/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-creating-a-rails-instance-from-an-existing-mysql-db/) (for MySQL):

- Reference the db in config/database.yml
- Run “rake db:schema:dump”
- Convert schema.rb into db/migrate/001_create_database.rb

The issue I am facing is, whenever I run "rake db:migrate" the entire db refreshes and I lose all the pre-populated data. I got around this for awhile by running migrations first, then replacing the blank db that was generated with my pre-populated copy -- this allowed me to play around with my models in the rails console and see the data. However when I try to boot up the server on my local machine, I get a message that migrations are pending.

I am not quite sure what to do here...I've read that I should be seeding the db from "rake db:seed", but my existing db is quite large -- almost 1mm records, and when I attempted this (in albeit clumsy fashion) it ran for over 3 hours before I gave up. Any guidance on how to proceed is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrates should be used to create and changes the tables and fields, not load data, as you can see here [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)

If you want to import data you could do it on the seeds, but in your specific case it seems to me that you should create a dump from your origin database and load it on the target database.

Here is a tutorial [sqlite3: how to import/export data from/to a file](http://www.xappsoftware.com/wordpress/2013/01/24/sqlite3-how-to-importexport-data-fromto-a-file/)

Answer (score 0):

sqllite3 and MySQL are different things. My guess is you think you are connected to sqllite db but in reality you are connected to an empty MySQL db.

Answer (score 0):

Look into ActiveRecord migrations.

Here is a rails doc on ActiveRecord Migrations: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html